# React dot notation component passing between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, notation

How to pass Parent props boolean in to child component when using dot notation with functional component.

Component structure is

```
<Dropdown className="float-right">
  <Dropdown.Title>Open menu</Dropdown.Title>
  <Dropdown.Menu align="end">
    <Dropdown.Item className="hello mate" href="/dashboard">
      Dashboard
    </Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item className="hello mate" href="/settings">
      Settings
    </Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item className="hello mate" onClick={signOut}>
      Sign out
    </Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Child component `<Dropdown.Title>` has `OnClick` to open `<Dropdown.Menu>

```
const DropdownTitle = (props) => {
  const { children, className } = props;
  const [openDropdown, setOpenDropdown] = useState(false);
  const toggleDropdown = () => setOpenDropdown(!openDropdown);
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={toggleDropdown}>{children}</button>
  );
};
```

How to pass the `openDropdown` prop to `<Dropdown.Menu>` from `<Dropdown.Title>`

[image: Edit young-smoke-c9glwr]

**Looking for solution with managing with `openDropdown.tsx` which can avoid additional coding when using the component `<Dropdown>`**

Comment: The common solution in react is to elevate the state to a shared ancestor component.  Have you tried that yet?  Does that fit your use-case?

Comment: @PsiKai looking for solution to pass between components when using this method  `Dropdown.Title = DropdownTitle; Dropdown.Menu = DropdownMenu; Dropdown.Item = DropdownItem; Dropdown.Divider = DropdownDivider;`

Comment: I modified your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-poincare-djdyrw?file=/src/App.js).  Does that work?

Comment: @PsiKai Basically looking for solution which manage with in `Dropdown.jsx` so that no need to write additional code just for dropdown wherever import the `Dropdown`. Like react bootsrap did https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Ok, I see.  You want `DropDown.jsx` to manage that state.  There is a solution for that too.  I can provide you with an example, if you would modify your question to encapsulate that requirement.

Comment: I don't get what this question has to do with dot notation. It makes absolutely no difference for how to share/pass state between components whether you refer to your title component as `<Dropdown.Title>` or `<DropdownTitle>`.

Comment: @Bergi Just making similar components to the React Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modified code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-poincare-djdyrw?file=/src/App.js)

What you can do is create a context that wraps your parent `Dropdown` component using `React.createContext`.  Then all the children of the `Dropdown` can receive the values that are passed through the context provider.

Set the `value` prop of the `Provider` component to be the state of the dropdown, and the dropdown toggle function.

```js
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const DropdownContext = createContext();

const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const { children, className } = props;
  const [openDropdown, setOpenDropdown] = useState(false);
  const toggleDropdown = () => setOpenDropdown(!openDropdown);

  return (
    <div
      className={`inline-flex flex-col relative ${className ? className : ""}`}
    >
      <DropdownContext.Provider value={{ openDropdown, toggleDropdown }}>
        {children}
      </DropdownContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then, to consume your context values, use React's `useContext` hook in the components that need them.

```js
const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
  const { children, className, align } = props;
  const { openDropdown } = useContext(DropdownContext);

  return (
    <div
      {...props}
      className={`
      flex-col absolute mt-1 py-1 top-full bg-white text-base z-50 rounded shadow min-w-[180px] 
      ${align === "start" ? "left-0" : "right-0"}
      ${className}
      ${openDropdown ? "inline-flex" : "hidden"}
      `}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const DropdownTitle = (props) => {
  const { children, className } = props;
  const { toggleDropdown } = useContext(DropdownContext);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={toggleDropdown}
      type="button"
      className={`inline-flex items-center gap-x-1.5 rounded-md bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 ${
        className ? className : ""
      }`}
    >
      {children}
      <svg
        className="w-4 h-4 ml-2"
        fill="none"
        stroke="currentColor"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          strokeWidth="2"
          d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"
        />
      </svg>
    </button>
  );
};
```

This solution will allow you to keep all the values incapsulated into one file.  Similar to the bootstrap method you linked here: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/dropdowns/